# font size don't work in canvas when setting the canvas width

Tags: canvas, font-size

when I set the width canvas, the fontSize in the canvas is not correct (too small) and i don't know why.

Here my source code :

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
c = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 

text = "Test";
ctx.font = "normal 12px sans-serif";
c.width = 200;
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 20);
</script>
```

Have you an idea ?

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You first need to set the desired `canvas` width.**
Otherwise a 12px font will be first painted on a 300px (default width) canvas. 
If you resize the canvas AFTER the text is already in context, logically the text will end up smaller since the canvas size changed to `200` **afterwards**.

```js
c = document.getElementById("canvasa");
c.width = 200; // HERE!!!!!!
ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 


text = "Test";
ctx.font = "normal 12px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText(text, 0, 20);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasa"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, but When you want modify the canvas width, the fontSize is not correct in the canvas. I have just post a new post to explain this.

Comment: Yes I understand the fontSize problem when resizing the canvas dimensions.